# How to return to parent directory?

Tags: linux, bash, command, slurm, hpc

I want to change my directory to the script's parent directory when running the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=INCAR  #JobName
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.(skip)

module load intel/2020a
module load impi/2019.7.217
module load vasp/6.3.0
vdir="$(dirname "$0")"
echo "$vdir"
cd "$vdir"
export I_MPI_PMI_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/libpmi.so

srun vasp_std > OUT 2> ERR
```

I added the echo to figure out what is going wrong, and I only get this output:

```
/var/spool/slurmd/job7886257
```

and I didn't change the directory successfully after running the script.
There is also an error message about the last line of the script:

```
/var/spool/slurmd/job7886257/slurm_script: line 29: OUT: Permission denied
```

What is the reason behind this and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: `cd` changes the directory for the process that runs the script, not for the process you called the script from.

Comment: Check the permissions for the directory and check that no file named OUT already exists there (if it does, check the permissions for it; also consider whether you really want to overwrite it).

Comment: Seems like it's the first case. Is there anything I can do to change my directory to where I called the script? (e.g. /home/myfolder/Research/)

Comment: The only way is to source the script. Instead of running `script.sh`, run `. script.sh`. The `.` tells bash to run the script in the environment instead of creating a sub-environment (aka sourcing the script).

Comment: You say that you get an error on line 29, but you don't tell us, which line this is.

Comment: How do you call the script??? `sbatch path/to/script` or `./path/to/script` or `cd path/to/; sbatch script`?

Comment: line 29 is the last line: srun vasp_std > OUT 2> ERR

Comment: I used qsub   But I have fixed the problem in a different way through calling the script from another script.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question if you want the directory the script is running in or the directory the script is defined in so here's how to get both.

Within your script to print the directory you called it from (and so it's running in) would just be:

```
rundir="$( pwd )"
echo "$rundir"
```

If instead you wanted to print the directory that the script is defined in then, in `bash`, that'd be:

```
srcdir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo "$srcdir"
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat $HOME/bin/tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rundir="$( pwd )"
echo "rundir=$rundir"

srcdir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo "srcdir=$srcdir"

$ cd "$HOME/tmp"

$ tst.sh
rundir=/home/myname/tmp
srcdir=/home/myname/bin
```

I'm assuming you want to store that value in a variable.

Here's one use case where just calling `dirname "$0"` isn't adequate to get the literal source directory for the command:

```
$ cat "$HOME/bin/tst.sh"
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rundir="$( pwd )"
echo "rundir=$rundir"

srcdir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo "srcdir=$srcdir"

reldir="$( dirname "$0" )"
echo "reldir=$reldir"

$ ../../*/*/../../*/*/tst.sh
rundir=/home/myname/tmp
srcdir=/home/myname/bin
reldir=../../myname/somedir/../../myname/bin
```

and links are another.

Regarding `/var/spool/slurmd/job7886257/slurm_script: line 29: OUT: Permission denied` - it's exactly that, you don't have permission to write to that file or the directory its in.

Regarding `and I didn't change the directory successfully after running the script` - right, changing directory inside a script doesn't change your directory outside of the script (unless you execute the script as `. script` to make it change your current environment of course).

Answer (score 1):

When Slurm starts your job, it will indeed `execv` a **copy** of the submission script, that it saves into the `/var/spool/slurmd/` directory, but it will also `cd` into the submission directory (which is saved in the [SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR) environment variable.

Unless you want to change directory from the one you ran the `sbatch` command in, you do not need the `cd`. This behaviour is different from PBS for instance, where you indeed have to change directories explicitly at the start of the job.

Remove the lines

```
vdir="$(dirname "$0")"
echo "$vdir"
cd "$vdir"
```

from your submission script and your job should behave as you expect.